# Using vhost for JSS Multi-site setup on Azure App Service

Tags: azure, multisite, jss, vhost

I have a headless proxy multisite setup locally using JSS. I have two sites, SiteA and SiteB. I'm using vhost in node to serve as a middleware to resolve the hostname.

http://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/vhost.html

This is my server.js that works locally.

```
// For any other requests, we render app routes server-side and return them

const siteAUrl = 'sitea.com';
const siteBUrl = 'siteb.com';


// site a
const siteA = express();
const siteAConfig = getConfig('sitea');
siteA.use('*', scProxy(siteAConfig.serverBundle.renderView, siteAConfig, siteAConfig.serverBundle.parseRouteUrl));
server.use(vhost(siteAUrl, siteA));

// site b
const siteB = express();
const siteBUrl = getConfig('siteb');
siteB.use('*', scProxy(siteBUrl.serverBundle.renderView, siteBUrl, siteBUrl.serverBundle.parseRouteUrl));
server.use(vhost(siteBUrl, siteB));


server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('server listening on port: ', port);
});

server.keepAliveTimeout = 30 * 1000;

server.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.setTimeout(30 * 1000); // 30 second timeout
});
```

Once this app is deployed to an azure app service it is erroring and giving 500 errors. I have checked all the logs and I'm not receiving any info telling me why I'm getting 500 errors just the generic IIS 500 Internal Server Error HTML printed in the console.

I think I have narrowed the error down to using vhost. When I remove the use of vhost it works.

```
server.use('*', scProxy(config.serverBundle.renderView, config, config.serverBundle.parseRouteUrl));
```

but I lose my multisite functionality with this.

Do I need to do anything additional on azure to enable using vhost on the app service or can I use something similar to vhost to achieve the same thing?

Thank you!

Sitecore Version: 9.2 JSS

Comment: The below blog post could help to implement the multisite for Sitecore JSS. https://sivalingaamorthy.medium.com/how-to-setup-multi-site-using-vhost-for-sitecore-headless-ssr-proxy-95ac350806b

Answer (score 0):

The reason vhost wasn't working for me is because our sitecore implementation is behind a reverse proxy. Vhost doesn't support being behind a reverse proxy at the moment.

[Github vhost issue](https://github.com/expressjs/vhost/issues/20)

With a simple modification to the package, you can modify vhost to support reverse proxies.